# How to Move an Enemy After Spawn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still having a little bit of difficulty getting this to work. In short, I just need an enemy in Unity/C# to transform.Translate across the screen once instantiated. The enemies instantiate in the given X coordinates and random Y coordinates perfectly, but then they just sit there once instantiated. I put this script below on an empty game object.

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class CowLauncher : MonoBehaviour

{

    public float delay = 0.1f;
    public GameObject cow;
    public bool spawnedTrue;

    void Start ()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", delay, delay);
        spawnedTrue = false;
    }

    void Spawn ()
    {
        Instantiate(cow, new Vector2(3.59f, Random.Range(-0.5f, 1)), Quaternion.identity);
        spawnedTrue = true;
    } 
}
```

Then, from advice below from Adrian I went ahead and created a new script for the cow prefab and put this new script on the cow prefab.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveCow : MonoBehaviour {

    public int cowSpeed;
    public bool spawnedTrue;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if (spawnedTrue)
        {
            transform.Translate(cowSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Anything I can add to clarify question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're moving cow launcher, not the cows themselves. Attach new script with

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (spawnedTrue)
    {
        transform.Translate(cowSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

to cow prefab/gameObject and you should be good.

Comment: I actually did this, and nothing happened. I made a new script called CowMover, and copied this onto CowMover - complete with reference at the top of CowMover of the public bool spawnedTrue

Comment: Can you make screenshot with your scene hierarchy/objects properties?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out just by looking at this script above. I won't know 100% till I get back to my computer, but the problem seems to lie in the fact that I made the boolean private up above.

Comment: Really, thank you for your help Adrian!

Comment: Actually, I did this and nothing happened. Please see edited scripts above in original question.

Comment: I got it now! The public bool was unnecessary, and that was it!